# Gravity Forms - Populate Dynamically via AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

My issue is as follows:

1. I have an order form, which has a shipping field.
2. When the user clicks on a certain add item the shipping value should update (via query string)

What I need to know is how I would pass my query string to the URL using AJAX to update the value in real time.

I have a good working knowledge of javascript/jquery, but not a whole lot having to do with manipulating PHP.

my query string is: `shippingCost=$30.00`

or i suppose if it needs encoded: `shippingCost=%2430.00`

Thanks in advance, all suggestions are appreciated, don't necessarily need it spoon fed, just need pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Are you using Gravity Forms' dynamic field population? Are you triggering a page reload with the new URL, or not? If not, why not just use javascript to update the field value? What do you need the PHP for?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response...The issue is when you try to populate the field value via JavaScript, which was of course my initial inclination, the form throws an error on submit...Yes I am using Dynamic Population. The query string method was the only one I thought would be a plausible solution as the shortcode method isn't necessarily JS friendly, and neither is using action hooks.

Comment: Hmm, what's the error when you change the value with javascript?

Comment: Actually, I just solved my own problem. When I was testing I only changed the value of the relevant hidden input, for some reason you have to change the value of the span(label) AND the input...kinda weird but it works...Thanks again!

Comment: Share your code. Others could benefit.

Answer (score 0):

To other that may be looking for this. In order to let you change products price dynamically with AJAX and JS for example you need to enable **price dynamic population** or the form will pop and error on submission.

So enable dynamic population of the field and then update the price with javascript by changing the label and hidden field. E.g :

```
$('#input_2_15').html( r.precio );
$('#ginput_base_price_2_15').val( r.precio );
```